# Angular: switchMap UnsubscriptionError

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have a type-ahead functionality implmented using the below code.

```
accounts = new Subject<string>();

search(account) {
    this.accounts.next(account);
}

this.accounts
      .debounceTime(300)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(account => account
        ? this.tpiService.searchAccount(account)
        : Observable.of<any>([]))
      .subscribe(response => this.matchedAccounts = response);
```

If I type in the textbox when there's an ongoing request, it's getting cancelled, but a new request is not sent then. On the next keystroke only a new request is sent. I've attached the trace of my console when this happens. I can't get what's happening.

Please help.

[image: Error]

Comment: the error is happening somewhere else, you have a null reference error when you're trying to call "split" on something. Ii could be in your tpiService call or it could be in your template.

Comment: No, I'm nowhere trying to call `split`

Comment: you might be using a library that is trying to call split, but it's happening somewhere else.